# which xml file configuration will be loaded first and what will be the execution flow in Spring mvc web application

Tags: java, xml, apache, spring-mvc, xmlhttprequest

In spring mvc web application ,the first page that will be loaded will be the html or jsp page present in the welcome file list of web..xml in webINF directory,but there also another set of configuration given for server which also had web.xml .So my question is which xml configuration will be loaded first and how will be its flow because in that particular web application there first page was not present in the welcome file list but they had context scanning specified in server configuration so what will be my flow of web application from configuartion file in spring mvc web application.